# xslt use last 15 characters if length greater than 15

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Hoping someone can help me with this and i hope i explain it good enough for someone to be able to understand.

Basically in the xml file being being sent there is a tag "InvBatchNr" the length of this value in this could be anything, however the system i am trying to upload into can only accept 15 characters, so i want the style sheet to handle this situation.

So, if the length of "InvBatchNr" is greater than 15 characters, then take the last 15 characters, if not greater than 15 then use the whole value of "InvBatchNr"

Example:
The XML contains

```
<InvBatchNr>A00006_54324033_PRIMA01ES</InvBatchNr>
```

With the stylesheet in this example i want to extract '24033_PRIMA01ES'

This is what i have tried so far

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="string-length('InvBatchNr') &gt; 15">
<xsl:value-of select="substring('InvBatchNr', string-length('InvBatchNr'), -15)"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select='InvBatchNr'/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

And despite this not giving me any errors the value returned is actually blank.
Any pointers where i am going wrong would be great

Thanks in advance
Alan

Comment: You haven't said which XSLT version you are using. Whenever you want to do anything a bit complicated in XSLT, the answer is going to depend on which version you have. So please tag your question accordingly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referencing an element, `InBatchNr` should not have quotes around the element name. Your example is selecting the string literal instead of XPath to select the element named `InBatchNr`. Change `string-length('InvBatchNr') &gt; 15` to `string-length(InvBatchNr) &gt; 15`, and also adjust inside the substring.

If you want to select the [`substring()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-substring) of the last 15 characters, the second parameter should be the position of the character to start at. You are saying to start at the position of `string-length()` and continue for `-15` characters.

Instead, you want to start at `string-length(InBatchNr) - 14`, and then either specify to read 15 characters, or not specify the third parameter so that it reads to the end of the string.

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="string-length(InvBatchNr) &gt; 15">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(InvBatchNr, string-length(InvBatchNr) - 14)"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="InvBatchNr"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however if i use your answer it is still returning blank value

Comment: Are you sure that you are selecting a value that is greater than 15 characters, and not selecting nothing? Try with a hard-coded value: `substring('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', string-length('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') - 15)` which produces: `klmnopqrstuvwxyz`

Comment: Ok if i hardcode and use this

'code'
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')&gt; 15">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', string-length('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') - 15)"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="InvBatchNr"/>
   </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
'code'

Then my returned value is 'klmnopqrstuvwxyz', so why would the example i gave in the original post not work as this is greater than 15 characters, or is the hyphens in the string causing issues?

Comment: Sounds to me like you aren't actually selecting the element value that you think you are. As I pointed out in my answer, the code that you posted is testing the literal string "InBatchNr" and not performing an XPath to select that element. Remove the single quotes around the element name.

Comment: Ok got it working now, thank you so much for you help, I forgot that the template was using a leading value to all tags so I needed this and now all is good.